# Cannot transfer values from python to variable defined in Fortran by using s = system()

Tags: python, fortran, abaqus

I want to call python code in Fortran and transfer values generated in python to Fortran using system() command. However, it doesn't work.
here is my fortran code:

```
program SystemTest
  character(len=256) :: cmd
  integer :: py
  print *, "FORTRAN: BLOCKING"
  py = system("python python_number.py")
  print *, py
  py = 2
  print *, py
  print *, "FORTRAN: EXIT"
end program SystemTest
```

and this is the python code I want to call:

```
def generate_a_number(a):
    return a
generate_a_number(2)
```

and I got this printed results:

```
 FORTRAN: BLOCKING
           0
           2
 FORTRAN: EXIT

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.141 s
Press any key to continue.
```

the returned value is always 0. I wonder whether the command system() can be used to transfer data. if not, how to obtain data from python.
any suggestion will be appreaciated.

Comment: `system` is not a standard Fortran function, so please tell us about your compiler.

Comment: @francescalus, that right, better to use standard function Fortran2008: execute_command_line().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `system()` returns only the status of execution. To get the result from Python script, you can write it to a file:

```
call system("python python_number.py > tmp.txt")
open(11, file="tmp.txt")
.......
```